# AngularJS: to do list with categories(ex. work) using meanstack?

Tags: mongodb, angularjs

to learn angularJS i followed along and made a simple todo list. the trouble im having is having each todo apart of a category, ex. work/school. Would I do that through mongoDB.. im confused how to go about this. any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need a way to store a category of a todo item somewhere. So having a property in a Mongo document is an obvious choice.

In the front end (angular), you have a few options. You could, for instance, get a list of all categories (from Mongo) and then get items for each category. Alternatively, you could get all todo items, iterate them and assign to different e.g. array based on the category, using AngularJS.

Comment: so eeverytime the user adds a todo, angular would iterate over all the items and assigns a category to those that dont have one?

Comment: well, when adding a new item you already know the category so no need to iterate. if you have an array for each category, you can push item object to the array.